# Mac hash function broken

Tags: encryption, hash

I'm more or less attempting to determine crypography algoirthms and how they work.  I'm a little confused on proving how one is trivial.

For example:

MAC(xbit_key,Message) = xbit_hash(Message) XOR xbit_key

Comment: I think the question is "WTF?!"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) for a general explanation and [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) for a good example. If it's still not clear, come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I still find it slightly confusing.  The question I posed was equivalent to the mathematical equivalence of a specific MAC algorithm.  For example as shown in HMAC, the mathematical equivalence is: HMAC(K,m) = H((K ⊕ opad) ∥ H((K ⊕ ipad) ∥ m)).  I'm trying to determine why my example Algorithm can be trivially broken, which I believe would make use of the birthday attack (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack), in proving that there is a likely chance of collision.  Or maybe the issue is that my algorithm merely XOR's the K w/ Hashed Message, which might not be secure.

Comment: @DJPlayer: No need for birthdays. The only secret component is the xbit_key. So given a message M "secured" with your MAC, all the attacker does is XOR your MAC with xbit_hash(M) and, voila, out pops the xbit_key.

Comment: @GregS: Yes, this is just a reinvention of the "ultra-secure" technique of XORing with a password. Scare quotes intentional!